# Desencriptar Arreglo Base64 en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, base64

Hola tengo un arreglo cifrado en base64 y cuando lo desencripto lo hace con caracteres que desearía eliminar:

```
  const b64_to_utf8 = (str) => {                           
      return new Buffer(str, 'base64').toString('ascii')   
  }
```

Decifrado se ve así:

[image: arreglo]

¿Es posible quitar los caracteres?

intente con un `.split('\n');` pero no funcionó.

Answer (score 2):

Lo he solucionado!

Básicamente los caracteres se generaba porque en ningún momento lo transformaba a lo que realmente era un `json`, si no mas bien continuaba siendo un string. por otra parte también influyo el codigo de caracter `ascii` la cual no permitía transformarlo a `JSON` generando el error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 782

al cambiarlo al formato de codificación `utf-8` permitio parsear el string y trasnformalo a un `JSON`.

Como resultado final el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
let Mybase64 = '//*...*//'

const b64_to_utf8 = str => JSON.parse(new Buffer(str,'base64').toString('utf-8'));

b64_to_utf8(Mybase64);
// return JSON
```

Comment: solo añade una explicación del procedimiento que seguiste, para que la respuesta sea descriptiva para otros usuarios con la misma duda, mientras te doy un +1

Comment: oki, si tienen alguna mejor explicación sería de ayuda jajaj, saludos.